# Retrieving report colums in Event Monitoring

Tags: api, event, reports-api, eventlogfile, monitoring

I'm trying to understand if it's possible within Event Monitoring to retrieve report columns for the Event Type "ReportExport". Our client would like to know, without a manual check, wich are the columns contained in the report exported.

I understand that there isn't this info in the EventLogFile, but would it be possible to use API in order to retrieve also this info, based on the id of the report exported?

I was looking at this example in Apex: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_metadata.htm
but this require to run each report programmaticly in order to get its metadata.

Does anybody have some hints on this?

Thanks
Fabio